# Concatenate AWS Secrets in aws-cdk for ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

how do you go about making a postgres URI connection string from a `Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret()` call without writing the secrets out using `toString()`?

I think I read somewhere making a lambda that does that, but man that seems kinda overkill-ish

```
  const dbCreds = Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret("postgres")
  const username = dbCreds.username
  const password = dbCreds.password
  const uri = `postgresql://${username}:${password}@somerdurl/mydb?schema=public`
```

Pretty sure I can't do the above. However my hasura and api ECS containers need connection strings like the above, so I figure this is probably a solved thing?

Comment: Hey! How did you manage to do it? I'm facing the same issue right now..

Comment: You can use `.unsafeUnwrap()` on a secret to do this, however it will embed the secret into your CF template. Which is bad in most cases.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/23613

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a secret that already exists in the Secret's Manager you could just do a lookup of the secret by name or ARN. Take a look at the documentation referring [how to get a value from AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/get_secrets_manager_value.html).

Once you have your secret in the code it is easy to pass it on as an environment variable to your application. With CDK it is even possible to pass secrets from Secrets Manager or AWS Systems Manager Param Store directly onto the CDK construct. One such example would be (as pointed in the documentation):

```
taskDefinition.addContainer('container', {
  image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"),
  memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
  environment: { // clear text, not for sensitive data
    STAGE: 'prod',
  },
  environmentFiles: [ // list of environment files hosted either on local disk or S3
    ecs.EnvironmentFile.fromAsset('./demo-env-file.env'),
    ecs.EnvironmentFile.fromBucket(s3Bucket, 'assets/demo-env-file.env'),
  ],
  secrets: { // Retrieved from AWS Secrets Manager or AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store at container start-up.
    SECRET: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(secret),
    DB_PASSWORD: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(dbSecret, 'password'), // Reference a specific JSON field, (requires platform version 1.4.0 or later for Fargate tasks)
    PARAMETER: ecs.Secret.fromSsmParameter(parameter),
  }
});
```

Overall, in this case, you would not have to do any parsing or printing of the actual secret within the CDK. You can handle all of that processing within you application using properly set environment variables.

However, only from your question it is not clear what exactly you are trying to do. Still, the provided resources should get you in the correct direction.

Comment: -1 What he is trying to do is create an interpolated string that contains a secret value that will get expanded during deployment, in this case, for a connection string. Presumably this is to avoid having to modify the application at all (which is my use case).